# Angularjs app - user input and output from JSON

Tags: angularjs, json

I've done this already in native Javascript, but I want to do it in Angular now.

I want to create a simple app where a user inputs the name of a city, and gets an output of restaurants in that city along with the name of the restaurant and the address. I was able to successfully output the data with a pre-defined city, but I can't seem to do it with user input. I'm not sure how to get the value of "city_name" into the url in the controller.

Here is what I have so far. I want the content of the table inside the div to appear only on click of the Submit button.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Restaurant App</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="restaurantApp">
        <input type="text" ng-model="city_name"</input>
        <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
        <div ng-controller="restaurantController">
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurantList">
                    <td>{{restaurant.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{restaurant.address}}</td>
                    <td>{{restaurant.price}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            //var city = 'chicago';

            angular.module('restaurantApp', [])
            .controller('restaurantController', function($scope, $http) {
                $http.get(`http://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/restaurants?city=${$scope.city_name}`).
                then(function(response) {
                    $scope.restaurantList = response.data.restaurants;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your implementation:

1. You've used AngularJS Controller Method like `submit` outside the `div` where you've used `ng-controller` directive. So AngularJS will have no idea about that.
2. Second, you didn't define the `submit` method in your controller.

Fixing these two issues should make it work..

Here, try this(by clicking on the **Run Code Snippet** button):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Restaurant App</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="restaurantApp" ng-controller="restaurantController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="city_name">
  <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurantList">
        <td>{{restaurant.name}}</td>
        <td>{{restaurant.address}}</td>
        <td>{{restaurant.price}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script>
    //var city = 'chicago';

    angular.module('restaurantApp', [])
      .controller('restaurantController', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.submit = function() {
          $http.get(`http://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/restaurants?city=${$scope.city_name}`).
          then(function(response) {
            $scope.restaurantList = response.data.restaurants;
          });
        }

      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, working code (you just need to add submit function, which takes `ng-model` from `input`: 
JS:

```
$scope.submit = function(city){
          console.log(city);
       $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/restaurants?city=' + city,
        })
        .then(function successCallback(data) {
        $scope.restaurantList = response.data.restaurants;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log('error');
       });
      }
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="city_name"/>
        <button ng-click="submit(city_name)">Submit</button>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurantList">
                    <td>{{restaurant.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{restaurant.address}}</td>
                    <td>{{restaurant.price}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qgsnR8mDxi9QcwlUk9Mp?p=preview